# Display a List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> in a dropdown and update other fields with nested values

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have form fields Server Name, Server IP, Database, and Port. I need the Server Name field to be a dropdown whose values are the keys `serverName1` and `serverName2` from the `List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>` below. Then, when the user selects either one, the other fields should update with the appropriate nested values (Server IP, Database, Port). How do I do this?

```
class GlobalsProvider {

List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> getServers() {
  final serverList = [{
    'serverName1': {
      'Server IP': 'ip1',
      'Database': 'db1',
      'Port': 'port1'
    },
    'serverName2': {
      'Server IP': 'ip2',
      'Database': 'db2',
      'Port': 'port2'
    }
  }];

  return serverList;
}

}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Login'),
              centerTitle: true,
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add)
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Visibility(
                      visible: true, 
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Expanded(child: Text('Server Name:')),
                          DropdownButton(
                            //? Not sure how to do this part
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Visibility(
                      visible: true, 
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Expanded(child: Text('Server IP:')),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: serverIPController,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Visibility(
                      visible: true, 
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Expanded(child: Text('Database:')),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: dbController,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Visibility(
                      visible: true, 
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Expanded(child: Text('Port:')),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: portController,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                 //...
```

Comment: currently you are having single item on serverList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a single list item with two server. In this case it will be

```dart
  String? selectedServer;

  final TextEditingController serverIPController = TextEditingController();
  void onServerChanged(String? value) {
    setState(() {
      selectedServer = value; 
                                /// having single item on the list, so index is 0
      serverIPController.text = serverList[0][selectedServer]?['Server IP'] ?? "";
    });
  }
```

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Text('Server'),
    Expanded(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: selectedServer,
        hint: const Text('Select Server'),
        items: serverList[0].keys.map((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: onServerChanged,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
Row(
  children: [
    const Expanded(child: Text('Server IP:')),
    Expanded(child: TextField(controller: serverIPController)),
  ],
),
```